# Verify hostname or IP address before request processing ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to make my ASP.NET MVC 3 web app to run on particular hostname or IP address only. If someone tries to host the site on different host or IP address, the website should stop working as it see the hostname/IP address different than configured (basically, hardcoded in the app DLL).

Any idea how effectively this can be achieved in ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: You said: _"If someone tries to host the site on different host or IP address"_  Do you intend to distribute your system, binaries-only?

Comment: Yes, that's right! I am open to hear if there any better approach than this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Global.asax file create new BeginRequest function:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)sender;

    if (application.Request.Url.Host != "mydomain.com")
    {
        application.CompleteRequest();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter requests using [HTTP Module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998536.aspx).

Comment: Any ASP.NET MVC way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to accomplish it 
is creating an action attribute to validate that request :P

```
public class HostValidatorAttribute : ActionMethodSelectorAttribute 
{
   public override bool IsValidForRequest(ControllerContext controllerContext, System.Reflection.MethodInfo methodInfo) 
   {
       //validate here and returns true if valid
   }
}
```